# How to present an object oriented code with python jupyter note book?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter notebook and I want to present my object-oriented code with it.
My problem is it doesn't recognize methods of my classes.
I mean I want to explain each part of my code so I put each method in one cell.
now when I call a method I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-4bb647616f28> in <module>
----> 1 s.plot_numpy_array()

AttributeError: 'Classification' object has no attribute 'plot_numpy_array'
```

You can see my jupyter notebook in this image:
[image]

I mean is there any way to have object-oriented code which all methods are not in a cell? or at least can explain each method separately in a clear way?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use markdown instead:

1- create your class in one cell of code (this is the only way it will execute peoperly.
2- create markdown cells that contain the parts of code you want to highlight and their explanation:

#### Markdown cell:

(not rendered)

````
```python
def __init__(self, *args):
   ...
```
Blurb of prose explaining what you need to. Can include Latex, pictures, etc.
````

-> The code between the triple 'ticks' will render with the proper syntax highlighting.

Comment: Strange your answer haven't been accepted, but it deserves.

Comment: Thank you @prosti

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep all the functions in the same cell, correctly indented to your class. What you try to do is not supported by Jupyter notebook.

A combination of comments and markdown might be the best alternative to have clean documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cell as markdown, and use syntax highlighting with TAB, single quote(`) and triple quote (```).

You can also use `?` (question mark) or `??`. It will provide excellent documentation for your classes.

Take this Python code for instance:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

for i in range(5):
    ax.plot(x, i * x, label='$y = %ix$' % i)

ax.legend()
plt.show()

?plt
```

[image]